# Azure backup report using powershell

Tags: azure, backup

I am trying to pull azure backup report using recovery service vault. I am using az backup job list but not able to pull backup job list for mabs

I am trying to pull azure backup report using recovery service vault. I am using az backup job list but not able to pull backup job list for mabs

Also, I need to filter using date time for the job report.In my environment jobs are scheduled like yesterday 10pm to today 10pm..

Please help me with the command

Answer (score 0):

> I need to filter using date time for the job report.In my environment jobs are scheduled like yesterday 10pm to today 10pm

To pull `Azure backup` job list using the **Azure CLI** `az backup job list` command for `Azure Backup Server` and filter the job report based on a specific **Date** and **Time** range, you can use below `PowerShell` command.

```
 az backup job list --resource-group "RG-Name" --vault-name "Vault-Name" --end-date 17-07-2023-13:28:47 --start-date 16-07-2023-10:28:47
```

**Output:**

[image]

If you want to run the script from automation, kindly authenticate using a service principal and assign the required role to the service principal

```
$tenantId = "650cxxxxxxx-a944-627017451367"
$appId = "e47444ef-xxxxxx-a7f0-83dbab1feb64"
$appSecret = "yhn8Q~xxxxxxxxxxHSEfiQNRH3ypHybNN"
    
$secureAppSecret = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $appSecret -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $appId, $secureAppSecret
    
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $cred -TenantId $tenantId
    
$Recoverydetails = az backup job list --resource-group "RG-name" --vault-name "vaultname" --end-date "17-07-2023-13:28:47" --start-date "16-07-2023-10:28:47" | ConvertFrom-Json
    
 $Recoverydetails | Export-Csv -Path "/home/user/recovertreport.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

The above script will authenticate using a service principal and generate the Azure backup report to Excel

> Note: Modify the command as per your requirement

Add the same script to the Task Scheduler to run the script every day.

[image]

Reference: [List all backup jobs of a Recovery Services vault.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/backup/job?view=azure-cli-latest#az-backup-job-list)